# Query parameter not being extracted - JAX-RS and Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API but I'm having difficulty using @QueryParam to extract the query parameters from a POST request even though my resource method is being called.

This is my resource method:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response test(@QueryParam("test-param") String testParam) 
{
    String response = "testParam is: " + testParam + "\n";
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(response).build();
}
```

I'm using cURL to submit the HTTP POST request as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.0.2:8080/myApp/test --data test-param=Hello
```

The value returned is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use curl -X POST 'http://192.168.0.2:8080/myApp/test?test-param=Hello'

Comment: Since the `--data` option sends the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you should be annotating your method parameter with [@FormParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html).  The JAX-RS specification states that @QueryParam “Specifies that the value of a method parameter, class field, or bean property is to be extracted from a URI query parameter.”  So even though a query parameter can technically reside in either the URI query part, or in the request body, @QueryParam only reads query parameters from the URI itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --data in curl will provide the whole text `test-param=Hello`. The correct way to request it is:

`curl -X POST http://192.168.0.2:8080/myApp/test?test-param=Hello`

Comment: When using POST you can send more than just parameters, you can send a body full of text/binary... for instance a full JSON/XML object - something you will not include as a query parameter. If you change your signature to `public Response test(@QueryParam("test-param") String testParam, String body)` and use the request you sent primarily - you will see anything after the -data will be in the `body`

Answer (score 1):

try to use curl -X POST '192.168.0.2:8080/myApp/test?test-param=Hello';

-d, --data

(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.